# .ctags regex for text/markdown files (quickvixes welcome!)

Tags: regex, vim, ctags

Oddly enough(and several hours later), I still feel this should work.

I am using ctags.  The src directory also contain some .txt or .md files.
I would like to get the todo,note,etc tags and view them in quickfix, or write to file.

relevant part from my .ctags file:
`

```
"--langdef=text
"--langmap=text:.txt
--regex-txt=/#TODO(.*)todo\1/
... 
--regex-markdown=/#TODO(.*)todo\1/
```

`

I do not want to just generate my own tags file, because it is mixed with src that gets its own tags file from ctags.  ( Also for future use, Id like to just be able to search from multiple files, or hardware(tablet, phone), and get all TODO tags from a vim server... )

Anyhow, how do I langdef for text and mardown?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want **vimgrep** for this particular use case. For example, opening vim in your source directory and entering `:vimgrep /^#TODO/i *.txt *.md` will populate the quickfix list with all the lines in text and markdown files which begin with #TODO. You can then use `:cnext` and `:cprev` to jump around the files.

Look at `:help vimgrep` and `:help :filename` for more information on **vimgrep** and the `{file}` argument respectively. You can expand the regex to match more tags (e.g. note) or use `:w` in your quickfix window to save the file.

Comment: awesome perfect for daily todo!\n I also ran into ack.vim which connects to quickfix as well! ...